# What is the shelf life for candy with fresh butter?

Tags: storage-lifetime, food-preservation

I am making a chocolate covered candy with a center that includes fresh butter, sugar and cookie crumbs.  There are no eggs in the recipe.  It is not cooked.  What is the shelf life before it needs to be refrigerated?

Comment: Unless you've got a recipe that says otherwise, I'd assume a couple of hours.  Clearly there are chocolate truffles using butter/cocoa/sugar that are shelf stable for much longer, but the proportion of sugar is important.

Comment: A couple of hours seems very conservative.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jay. If you live in a hot city (with temperatures above 30°C), I wouldn´t keep it out of the fridge more than a couple hours. Otherwise they should last at least five hours at room temperature.

Comment: Is this a food safety issue or just that it will melt into a puddle?

Comment: It´s not safety: butter makes a huge mess.